# get the two most used words in sentence in java

Tags: java, dictionary, count

How do I get the two most used words in a sentence for example here after it count the total number of appearances of all the words it should also display the two most used words

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Tokenizer

{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int index = 0; int tokenCount; int i =0;
    Map<String,Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    Map<Integer,Integer> letterCount = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    String message="The Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog";

    StringTokenizer string = new StringTokenizer(message);


    tokenCount = string.countTokens();
    System.out.println("Number of tokens = " + tokenCount);
    while (string.hasMoreTokens()) { 
          String word = string.nextToken().toLowerCase();
          Integer count = wordCount.get(word);
          Integer lettercount = letterCount.get(word);

          if(count == null) { 
          wordCount.put(word, 1);
        }
        else { 
          wordCount.put(word, count + 1);
        }
     }
    for (String words : wordCount.keySet())
        {System.out.println("Word : " +  words + " has count :" +wordCount.get(words));

    }
 }
```

Comment: What are you using `letterCount` for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate thorough the HashMap and then keep track of the highest counts.

```
int first, second;

first = second = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

String firstWord, secondWord;

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
{

   int count = entry.getValue();
   String word = entry.getKey();

    if (count > first)
    {
       second = first;
       secondWord = firstWord;
       first = count;
       firstWord = word;
    }
    else if (count > second && count != first)
    {
      second = count;
      secondWord = word;
    }
}

System.out.println(firstWord + " " + first);
System.out.println(secondWord + " " + second);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over map's entry set.

This will return you entry object which will contain key and max value.

```
Map.Entry<String, Integer> max = null;

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    if (max == null || entry.getValue().compareTo(max .getValue()) > 0)
    {
        max = entry;
    }
}
```

For second most used word,i would say you can remove the max one and then again from this way,you can retrieve second one.

Comment: Why not do it both in the same loop?

Comment: Thanks @Uma Kanth sure we can do it and that would be better.I would update my answer.